# Filter on count(*) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a grouped query, and would like to filter it based on count(*)

Can I do this without a subquery?

This is what I have currently:

```
select * 
  from (select ID,
               count(*) cnt
          from name
      group by ID)
 where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

what you are looking for is the `HAVING` clause:

```
select ID, count(*) cnt
from name
group by ID
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: But if it came down to picking two identical answers entered at the same time, I think I'd go with Ponies over some guy named Eric :)

Comment: @chris - ponies are nice n all, but can you really trust a unicorn with a rainbow coming out of its ass?  I think not :)

Comment: Good point, but I'm sure you'd get an argument on that point from my daughter :)